# Update Trigger : Supertype/subtypes tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, insert-update, subtype, supertype

I need some help about triggers. I’m currently developing a platform and a database in order to manage exams at my university. Here is my problem:

I have 1 supertype table, which contains all the persons registered on the platform. I have to be able to make the distinction for each person between the functions “Candidate” and “Examiner”. So I have my 2 subtype tables, one for all the candidates and one for all the examiners. To achieve that, I’m using insert triggers.

In addition, a person can be both Candidate and Examiner, but not at the same time. So after updating the supertype table, I also need a trigger to be able to delete a specific row from one of the two-subtype table and insert the user information on the other.

Here is a simplified design of these 3 tables:

[image]

### My INSERT trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[role_insert]   
ON [dbo].[alemp_persons]  
FOR INSERT  
AS
  DECLARE @random_number int
  SELECT @random_number = CAST(CAST(rand() as binary(2)) as int)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.alemp_candidates 
  ( 
  id_person, random_number
  )  
  SELECT id_person, @ random_number
  FROM INSERTED  
  WHERE function='Candidate'

  INSERT INTO dbo.alemp_examiners
  (  
  id_person
  )  
  SELECT id_person
  FROM INSERTED  
  Where function='Examiner'
END
GO
```

### My UPDATE trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[role_update] ON [dbo].[alemp_persons]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  DECLARE @id_person int 
  DECLARE @newFunction int SELECT @newFunction=function FROM inserted
  DECLARE @random_number int SELECT @ random_number = CAST(CAST(rand() as binary(2)) as int)

IF @newFunction = 'Candidate'
BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM dbo.alemp_examiners
  WHERE id_person=@id_person
END

BEGIN
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.alemp_candidates ON;
  INSERT INTO dbo.alemp_candidates  
  (  
  id_person, random_number
  )  
  SELECT  @id_person, random_number
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.alemp_candidates OFF;
END

IF @newFunction = 'Examiner'
BEGIN
  DELETE 
  FROM dbo.alemp_candidates
  WHERE id_person=@id_person
END

BEGIN
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.alemp_examiners ON;
  INSERT INTO dbo.alemp_examiners
  (  
  id_person
  ) 
  SELECT  @id_person
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.alemp_examiners Off;
END
GO
```

As I said above, my INSERT trigger works as I want. However when I want to update the function of one person, I got an error :

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set
>   to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: BTW, triggers must be able to handle multiple rows....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple notes:

1) You should follow  Mitch Wheat's advice and rewrite these triggers because `inserted` and `deleted` tables could have more than one row. For example, your trigger will have a bad behavior when is executed the next statement `UPDATE [dbo].[alemp_persons]  SET function = CASE WHEN id_person = 1 THEN 'Candidate' ELSE 'Examiner' END WHERE id_person IN (1,2)` if the first person's function is 'Examiner' and the second person's function is 'Candidate'.

2) `[dbo].[alemp_persons].function`'s data type should be `[tiny]int` or `char(1)` and not `varchar(something greater than 1)` (`Where function='Examiner'`).

3) `[dbo].[alemp_persons].function` column should disallow Nulls.

4) `[dbo].[alemp_persons].function` column should has a CHECK constraint:

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[alemp_persons]
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_alemp_persons_function_Verify CHECK ( function IN ('Candidate', 'Examiner') );

5) It would be nice to add

- a `function` column to `[dbo].[alemp_candidates]` and `[dbo].[alemp_examiners]` tables,
- two check constraints on `[dbo].[alemp_candidates]` (`function = 'Candidate'`) and `[dbo].[alemp_examiners]` (`function = 'Examiner'`),
- an UNIQUE index on `[dbo].[alemp_persons](id_person, function)`,
- two FKs between `[dbo].[alemp_candidates/examiners](id_person, function)` and `[dbo].[alemp_persons](id_person, function)`.

This way, you can be sure that `[dbo].[alemp_candidates]` table has only candidates and `[dbo].[alemp_examiners]` has only examiners and every person can be only candidate or examiner at one time.

6) You should disallow `IDENTITY` property for `id_person` columns in `[dbo].[alemp_candidates]` and `[dbo].[alemp_examiners]` table (`SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.alemp_candidates ...`).

8) And this statement `IF @newFunction = 'Candidate'` should raise an error because `@newFunction` data type is 'INT'.

9) And the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on `[dbo].[alemp_persons]` table will move data between candidates and examiners tables (not tested):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[role_update]   
ON [dbo].[alemp_persons]  
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @selected_rows TABLE (
id_person INT PRIMARY KEY, -- or BIGINT, look at alemp_person.id_person data type 
new_function VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL -- look at alemp_person.function column data type 
);

INSERT @selected_rows (id_person, new_function)
SELECT new.id_person, new.function
FROM inserted as new INNER JOIN deleted as old ON new.id_person = old.id_person
WHERE new.function <> old.function;

MERGER dbo.alemp_candidates AS dest
USING @selected_rows AS src ON dest.id_person = src.id_person
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND src.new_function = 'Candidate' THEN
    INSERT (id_person, random_number)
    VALUES (src.id_person, CONVERT(BINARY(2), CHECKSUM(NEWID()));

MERGER dbo.alemp_examiners AS dest
USING @selected_rows AS src ON dest.id_person = src.id_person
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND src.new_function = 'Examiner' THEN
    INSERT (id_person)
    VALUES (src.id_person);
END
```